# Connection refused error while cloning from Git

Tags: git, yocto

I have seen many posts related to this error on stack overflow other forums as well but unfortunately I do not get any solution.
I am executing the following command on Ubuntu 14.04 machine

```
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky yoctoProject
```

and I am getting this error.

```
Cloning into 'yoctoProject'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.yoctoproject.org:
git.yoctoproject.org[0: 140.211.169.56]: errno=Connection refused
```

Replacing git:// with https:// does not resolve my issue. Can anybody suggest something different ??

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem, maybe it is a local network configuration problem.

Comment: Try to ping the server and check

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan Ping is working fine

Comment: @LeeDuhem Yes It was local network configuration problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Only 6 years late.

I came across the same problem today.

You can replace

```
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky yoctoProject
```

with

```
git clone https://git.yoctoproject.org/git/poky/ yoctoProject
```

Found [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2015-January/023007.html).